# pik Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, jruby, gsub, pik

I´m getting an error when adding JRuby 1.3.1 to pik. Error:

```
Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass
```

this is my path environment variable:

```
C:\Users\Owner>echo %path%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;c:\jruby-1.7.0.preview1\bin;C:\jruby-1.3.1\bin;c:\pik
```

this is when trying to add 1.3.1 version:

```
C:\Users\Owner>pik add C:\jruby-1.3.1\bin

There was an error.
 Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass

  in: pik/commands/command.rb:124:in `get_version'
  in: pik/commands/add_command.rb:23:in `add'
  in: pik/commands/add_command.rb:13:in `execute'
  in: pik_runner:33
```

It´s not the case when adding JRuby 1.7.0 version.

I have added JRuby 1.3.1 before to pik, but I don´t know what might be causing this error this time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the command `pik run PATH` with this result:

```
C:\Users\Owner>pik run PATH
Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\**bin**
```

So added to environment variables -> User variables

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
```

Now JRuby 131 has been added to my pik.

Regards